# Assembly 64 (NASM), ending of .data chars

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm, x86-64, glibc

I understand that in `.data` section there are arrays of chars, and last bit of array is null (0). Also, `10` is a code for new line. My question is, why when in `.data` section I delete `10` and left `0` program won't print anything, but when I delete `0` and left `10` program is working?

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
gwiazdka db '*',10,0      ;HERE is my question

section .text
main:
mov rbx, 0

petla:
mov rdi, qword gwiazdka
mov rsi, rbx
mov rax, 0
call printf

inc rbx
cmp rbx, 4
jne petla

mov rax, 1
int 80h
```

I want to build a square from stars and I don't get it why I can't print single chars without starting new line... 
I compile like that:

```
nasm -f elf64 program.asm
gcc program.o -o program
./program
```

Comment: You should not use the `exit` syscall, just return from `main` or at worst, `call exit`. Otherwise you won't let the C library flush its buffers so the last line gets stuck in them. Alternatively, use the `write` syscall and not `printf`.

Comment: @Jester: The [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has a canonical dup-target for these `_exit()`-without-flushing questions (search for "printf")